# MySQL - maximum value for a timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am using a MySQL database to store a range of inputs that feed a model. I have a number of different dates that are stored as `TIMESTAMP`.

However, some of the values can be hundreds of years in the future. When I look in the DB, they are stored as `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` when the actual *timestamp* should be something like `'2850-12-01 00:00:00'`.

While searching on Google, I noticed that the maximum value is sometime in 2038. Has anyone found a work-around for longer-dated timestamps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert them to `DATETIME`, it will store what you want. Compare:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table t (t timestamp, d datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.59 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into t values ('2850-12-01 00:00:00','2850-12-01 00:00:00');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| t                   | d                   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2850-12-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That worked a treat. I didn't realise that DATETIME was available in mySQL - a while back, someone had told me that when moving code from MSSQL to mySQL, you had to convert DATETIME to TIMESTAMP!